# Regex pattern not identifying pattern

Tags: android, regex

I'm using a regex pattern to extract matching items from a string

My pattern is :

```
"^(([^\\.\\-\\,a-wy-z]([\\(]?(\\+|[x])?\\d+[\\)]?)?[\\s\\.\\-\\,]?([\\(\\d[\\)]?)?[\\s\\.\\-\\,]?(\\d+[\\s\\.\\-\\,]?)+[^\\.\\-\\,a-z])|((\\+|[x])?\\d+))$"
```

My string is

```
"This is the string +971 987654321 form which +91 9876543210 all the phone number +91 987 654 3210 has to be extracted +91 987 654 3210 and displayed in the +971-98-7654321 logcat and the post office box  number is 233227"
```

But unfortunately the pattern is not identifying any matching pattern from the string. I have validated the expression from "Check RegExp" through intention action. Here the pattern successfully identifies all the phone numbers that i have used in my string

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: RegEx is considered a write only language for a reason.  That's a nearly impossible to read piece of code.  Regex on english strings, especially when trying to find something as ill formatted as a phone number, is generally not a good approach.

Comment: Assuming least number of 10 digits in phone number :- https://regex101.com/r/iO0dI3/1 will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming at least `10` digits in your phone number(excluding `+`, space, `-` etc.), this will work

```
\s+(\+[\d\s-]{10,})\s+
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iO0dI3/1)**

If you assume, there can be no spaces separating a number and word,then you can use

```
(\+[\d\s-]{10,})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @rock321987. That one really helped me